# Trigger my app from background when system event occurs :ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios app development,  Is there a way to trigger my app from the background when the user connects to a wifi network.I researched about it  and learnt it could be done with reachability but could not figure it out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: No this is not possible. You can detect a internet connection change in bekacground if you app falls in one of the background running mode: VOIP, Audio Playback, Location tracking or accessory. Otherwise your will become inactive when it goes to the background.

Comment: Thanks for your reply is it possible on Mac OS @rckoenes

Comment: On MacOS I don't think it should be a problem.

Comment: but I want it on ios is there a way around @ShubhamJain and @ rckoenes

Comment: I have no idea about this maybe @rckoenes can help you on this